# PDE Initial-Boundary value problem question

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The problem: The ends of a stretched string are fixed at the origin and at the point,  $ x=\pi$ on the horizontal x-axis. The string is initially at rest along the x-axis, and then drops under it's own weight. The veritcal displacement $y(x,t)$ satisfies the PDE:

$Y_{tt} = v^{2}Y_{xx} - g$

$ \big( 0 < x <\pi, t>0 \big)$

where $g$ is acceleration due to gravity. Write the above as an initial boundary-value problem, and show that the solution is given by

$y(x,t) = \frac{4g}{\pi v^{2}} \big [ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2n-1)x}{(2n-1)^{3}} \cos(2n-1)vt - \frac{\pi}{8}x(\pi - x) \big]$

I honestly have no idea how to set this up because the wording of this problem is confusing me.

Much help is appreciated.

Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

From "the string is initially at rest", we know that $\partial_{t}y(x,0) = 0$. From "along the $x$-axis", we have $y(x,0) = 0$. So our initial-boundary-value problem is
\begin{align}
y_{tt}  &= \nu^{2}y_{xx} -g, \qquad 
y(x,0) = 0, \qquad
\partial_{t}y(x,0) =  0, \qquad
y(0,t) = y(\pi, t) = 0
\end{align}
You can solve the inhomogeneous part of the equation by taking $y_{p}(x,t)$ to be a second order polynomial in $x$ and $t$, (which will differentiate down to a constant under the action of $\partial_{t}^{2} - \nu^{2}\partial_{x}^{2}$, i.e., take $y_{p}(x,t) = a_{20}t^{2}+a_{10}t + a_{11}tx + a_{01}x + a_{02}x^2 + a_{00}$. The conditions $y(0,t) = y(\pi,t) = 0$ imply that $y_{p}(x,t) = cx(x-\pi)$. Hitting this with $\partial_{t}^{2} - \nu^{2}\partial_{x}^{2}$ and setting the result $=-g$ shows $c = \frac{g}{2\nu^{2}}$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
y(x,t) = y_{h}(x,t) - \frac{g}{2\nu^{2}}x(\pi-x),
\end{align} 
where $y_{h}$ solves
\begin{align}
\partial_{t}^{2}y_{h}  &= \nu^{2}\partial_{x}^{2}y_{h}, \qquad 
y_{h}(x,0) = 0, \qquad
\partial_{t}y_{h}(x,0) =  0, \qquad
y_{h}(0,t) = y_{h}(\pi, t) = 0
\end{align}
By separation of variables and application of boundary conditions, we see that the eigenfunctions are of the form $\cos(\nu mt)\sin(mx)$, so
\begin{align}
y(x,t) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{m}\cos(\nu mt)\sin(mx)  - \frac{g}{2\nu^{2}}x(\pi-x).
\end{align}
Since $y(x,0) = 0$, then
\begin{align}
 \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{m}\sin(mx) =  \frac{g}{2\nu^{2}}x(\pi-x)
\end{align}
Multiplication by $\sin(\ell x)$ and integration over $[0,\pi]$ gives
\begin{align}
a_{\ell} &= \frac{g}{\pi\nu^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi} x(\pi -x) \sin(\ell x), \mathrm{d}x \\
&=\frac{2g(1-(-1)^{\ell})}{\pi \nu^2 \ell^3}
\end{align}
so that $a_{2n} = 0$ and $a_{2n-1} = \frac{4g}{\pi\nu^{2}(2n-1)^{3}}$, giving
\begin{align}
y(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4g}{\pi\nu^{2}(2n-1)^{3}}\cos((2n-1)\nu t)\sin((2n-1)x)  - \frac{g}{2\nu^{2}}x(\pi-x).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The vertical displacement $y(x,t)$ satisfies the PDE
$$y_{tt}=v^2y_{xx}-g$$ for $x \in (0,\pi)$ and $t>0$, together with the boundary conditions $$y(0,t)=y(\pi,t)=0$$ (since the ends are fixed), and the initial conditions $$y(x,0)=0, \quad y_t(x,0)=0 \qquad\text{for }x \in [0,\pi].$$ Notice that $y(x,0)=0$ since the string is initially at rest along the $x$-axis. Similarly, $y_t(x,0)=0$ since the string has no initial velocity.

Let $w(x,t)=y(x,t)+\frac{g}{2v^2}(\pi x-x^2)$ (the second term is the "steady-state" or "long-time" solution which appears after the Fourier series in the desired answer). Then $$v^2w_{xx}=v^2y_{xx}-g=y_{tt}=w_{tt},$$ and so $w$ satisfies the homogeneous wave equation $w_{tt}=v^2w_{xx}$ with homogeneous Dirichlet BCs (that is, $w(0,t)=w(\pi,t)=0$ for $t>0$), and initial conditions $$w(x,0)=\frac{g}{2v^2}(\pi x-x^2), \quad w_t(x,0)=0 \quad \text{for } x \in [0,\pi].$$ This is now a standard separation of variables problem.